# Where can I find Shayde Jon in Math Quest Room Recess?

Tags: math-quest

The question I have is regarding the browser game [Math Quest](https://www.roomrecess.com/mobile/MathQuest/play.html)

I have gotten decently far into the game, and I'm currently trying to obtain the Alpha Sword. One of the steps in obtaining the Alpha Sword is to talk to Shayde Jon, but the problem is that I can't find Shayde Jon anywhere. Talking to King Mathius, it seems that I have to look under a small pond, but that can be in numerous places, which I do not want to spend the time looking for(it would take forever). Also, it says to look "under a small pond", but as far as I'm aware, you can't really go underwater in this game, or go underground under the water(tried using the "Dig" skill while in water, but it just digs up loot like it normally does, instead of bringing you underground).  Could someone show me the steps to get to Shayde Jon, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Before following these steps, make sure you have the "Reveal" skill and the "Drain" magic scroll.*

---

The first thing you want to do to find Shayde Jon is to travel to this screen:
[image]
If you are unfamiliar with this place, this is the Viper's Nest in the Forest of Fayth. I have circled in red the location of the Viper's Nest on the map below:
[image]
The next thing you want to do is to walk into the pond in the Viper's Nest, and then cast "Drain". If done correctly, you should now be in an underground area like the one shown below:
[image]
Note that this is the area marked with ??? on the map. You can now simply proceed forward through the screens(there is only one way to go) until you reach the last screen. Use the "Reveal" skill and you should be able to see Shayde Jon, as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]
Talk to Shayde Jon to continue on with the Alpha Sword Quest.